# Defining a surjective function $f: S \to T$ where the set of preimage satisfy closure properties

Tags: functions, proof-explanation

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

> Let $S$ be a set and $E$ a subset of $\mathcal{P}(S)$ satisfying:
>
> i) $S \in E$;
>
> ii) if $A \in E$, then $S \setminus A \in E$;
>
> iii) if $A,B \in E$, then $A \cup B, A \cap B \in E$.
>
> Suppose that $S$ is finite. Prove that there exists a set $T$ and a surjective map $f: S \to T$ with $E = \{f^{-1} (A) \mid A \subset T\}$. What if $S$ is infinite?

I've tried quite a lot of things, but can't seem to make anything work. My most promising attempt is as follows.

> Define a relation $\sim$ on $S$ by $a \sim b$ if and only if $a \in E$ if and only if $b \in E$. Then $\sim$ is an equivalence relation:
>
> 1. Reflexivity: for every $a \in S$, we have $a \in E$ if and only if $a \in E$
> 2. Symmetry: if $a \sim b$, then $a \in E$ if and only if $b \in E$; therefore, we have $b \in E$ if and only if $a \in E$;
> 3. Transitivity: if $a \sim b$ and $b \sim c$, then $a \in E$ iff $b \in E$ and $b \in E$ iff $c \in E$. Stringing these together gives $a \in E$ iff $c \in E$.
>
> So $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, with equivalence classes given by
> $$
> [x] = \{y \in S \mid x \in E \iff y \in E\}. 
> $$
> Define $T := S/{\sim}$, the quotient of $S$ by $\sim$, and let $f: S \to T$ be the canonical quotient map sending $s \mapsto [s]$. This map is surjective, since each equivalence class is nonempty, and choosing a representative gives a preimage under $f$. It suffices to show that $E = \{f^{-1} (A) \mid A \subset T\}$. Define the set on the right-hand side by $X$, and let $Y \in X$. Then we have $Y = f^{-1} (A)$ for some $A \subset T$. In particular, $A = [a]$ for some $a \in S$. Then, as $f$ is surjective, we have $f(Y) = f(f^{-1} (A)) = A$.

At this point, I'm a bit stuff on how to proceed. I believe the inclusion $E \subset X$ is immediate by definition, but I'm not sure how to finish the proof that $X \subset E$ or how to treat the case where $S$ is infinite. It seems to me that the argument still goes through, as I didn't ever use the fact that $S$ is finite.

Comment: "In particular, $A=[a]$ for some $a \in S$" makes no sense: $[a]$ is an element of $T$, not a subset of $T$.

Comment: @azif00 This is a good point, but I think I may still be confused. So because $A$ is an arbitrary subset of $T$, it may be the union of two or more such classes (or empty, actually), but not, in general, an equivalence class itself. Is that the idea?

Comment: The point is that if $a \in S$, then we can't have $a \in E$, as elements of $E$ are subsets of $S$, not the elements of $S$. So your equivalence class is not something that makes sense.

Comment: I think the good equivalence class would be : $x \sim y$ if and only if for all $A \in E$, $x \in A \iff y \in A$.

Comment: @eti902 In that case, is the map still the canonical quotient map? I'm not sure how to define a map with domain $S$ in this case.

Comment: Yes, it would be the canonical quotient map. This equivalence relation is defined on $S$.

Comment: You then have to show that each equivalence class $[x]$ is an element of $E$, using the closure properties.

Comment: @eti902 Thank you, this is very helpful. Does anything change in the infinite case, though? The argument seems to work the same there.

Comment: I think it may not be the case that $[x]$ is an element of $E$, because your set is only closed for finite intersections. In the finite case, you can intersect all the sets containing $x$ to obtain $[x]$, but you can't in the infinite case (well you can, but it is not guaranteed to be in $E$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll summarize the comments so that the question has an actual answer.

Let $S$ be finite. Define an equivalence relation on $S$, where $x \sim y$ if and only if for all $A \in E$, $x \in A \iff y \in A$. Denote $[x]$ the equivalence class of $x$. Let $T = S/\sim$ and $f$ be the canonical quotient map.

Let $E_x = \{ A \in E \ | \ x \in A\}$. Because $S \in E$, $E_x$ is never empty. One can check that
$$
[x] = \displaystyle \bigcap_{A \in E_x} A.
$$
The inclusion $\subseteq$ is obvious. For the converse, suppose by contradiction that $y \in \displaystyle \bigcap_{A \in E_x} A$ but $y \notin [x]$. It means that there exists $A' \in E$ such that $y \in A'$ and $x \notin A'$. This implies that $(S \backslash A') \in E_x$, because it is closed under complement. This is a contradiction, because $y$ is in the intersection, so it has to be in every set of $E_x$.

Because $E$ is closed under ***finite*** intersections, we have that $[x] \in E$.

It remains to show that $A \in E$ if and only if $A$ is empty or $A = \displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^n [x_i]$ for $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in S$.

$(\implies)$ : First, the empty set is in $E$, because it is closed under complement and $S \in E$. So, $S\backslash S = \emptyset \in E$. Else, if $A \in E$ is not empty, then $(A/\sim) \in T$ is of this form. In effect, by construction of $\sim$, if $x \in A$, then $[x] \subseteq A$.

$(\impliedby)$ : $E$ is closed under ***finite*** unions and contains $\emptyset$.

So, we have that $E = \{f^{-1}(A) \ | \ A \subseteq T\}$.

The infinite case may not work, because an infinite intersection/union of sets in $E$ may not be in $E$.